# Promise<Hoge> Hogeの取り出し方

Tags: javascript, typescript

`Promise<>`の使い方を説明しているサイトがあったら教えてください。

hogeFunctionという関数があり、これが`Promise<T>`を返します。

この関数の返り値`T`の型の値を使いたいのですが、Promiseがじゃましてとりだせません。
Thenでは、引数有りの関数を使えないので・・・やはり`T t`が取り出せません・・
良い方法があればおしえてください。

Answer (score 2):

> Promise<>の使い方を説明しているサイトがあったら教えてください。

MDNに詳しい使い方が日本語で紹介されてましてので、こちらが参考になると思います。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

> navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMediaで悩んでいます。

getUserMediaで取得できるMediaStreamを取り出して別の関数で使いたい、と認識しました。
こんなかんじでthenの中から別の関数を呼び出すのでは、解決できないでしょうか？

```
const render = (stream) => {
  const video = document.getElementById("video");
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.play();
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
.then(stream => {
  render(stream);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```